# javaScript video with images

Tags: javascript, xml, html, image, video

I know that it's possible to take a series of images and use javascript to set opacity from 1 to 0 very quickly for each one in rapid secession. I have actually done it before very successfully, although I only used 41 images at approx. 720p.

My question though, is whether or not it would be practical to make an entire video (4-10 minutes long) using only html, css, and javascript. Obviously that would be too many images to leave in the cache, so you'd have to empty the cache every so often of particular images, and also this would require a pretty good internet connection, but do you think it would be worth while to attempt?

are there any obvious pro's and cons that you could think of for trying this?

(to be clear, I'm not asking for the code to achieve it as I have already developed most of it, just what you think in terms of practicality of it as opposed to youtube or vimeo etc...)

Comment: I wish this question doesn't get closed with the reason being "too broad" or "doesn't match the expected type of question which can be posted on SO" ;)

Comment: perhaps you could suggest an edit to improve it?

Comment: Oh no , you got me wrong.I didn't say this question is not as per standards. I meant that I wish people don't consider this as not per standards and vote to close the question.I wish to see what the answers might be!

Comment: worth while? imo, no. You could remake Ben Hur using only a pencil and  a rather large amount of notebooks, but would it be practical? No. In the end the choice is yours and yours alone. If you see the benefit in challenging yourself to create this, then go for it.

Comment: basically what I am trying to figure out (without actually testing it) is if a standard internet connection and device could play a series of 720p or 1080p images at 24-30 frames per second by loading them as it goes and deleting older frames every so often to improve speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plainly put, I don't think it's practical.

Here's a few reasons why:

- **Number of images.**  Videos tend to be around 30 frames per second. 
  For a 4 min video, that's roughly 7,200 images.
- **Download time.** Downloading 7,200 images at 720 pixels high would require a
  significant amount of bandwidth, not only for the user, but also for
  the server.
- **DOM load.**  7,200 images would require just as many DOM
  elements positioned correctly behind each other.
- **Rendering.**  Each
  time we do an animation (fadeout), the browser has to calculate what
  element is visible and what that means to the user (pixel color,
  etc.)

Of course, we can optimize this:

- **Download the images that is needed at that specified time.**  If the connection can download 30 images/second, then we load what we need and then initiate the play sequence.
- **Remove elements when it's done.**  As the sequence goes on, we can assume that those images are no longer needed.  When those images are done, we can destroy those elements and thus free up a few resources.
- **Put images on multiple sub-domains/locations.**  Browsers tend to download 1 asset per domain at a single moment. Modern browsers may download 6 or more.  But if we were to split those assets to multiple subdomains, we can increase that number of simultaneous downloads and thus increase response time.
- **Create large sprites.**  Have the sequence on one or several large sprites, and use Javascript to correctly position the element.  This allows us to have a single/few downloads and removes the overhead from multiple downloads.

Videos are encoded so that the browser doesn't have to do all those pixel calculations and animations.  Each frame isn't a full image, but rather a delta between the current and next frame.  (I'm overly simplifying this.)

But this method is constantly used for pieces that need interactivity, or want to get past iOS auto-play hangups.  Again, not practical for large sequences, but definitely doable for shorter sequences.

Comment: thank you for such a great answer! one correction though, I wouldn't be animating the elements, they'd just go instantly from opacity 1 to opacity 0. the problem with a large sprite is that with that many images, the full sprite would be over 30,000 pixels wide which current jpgs and pngs can't support (or at least not for web anyway). However, what if the javascript is just changing the background image out and you only use 1 element?

Comment: If the background image was replaced, then you'd need to preload those background images before they are displayed.

Comment: right, obviously. So there'd be x number of elements where x is the number of images loading at one time. Or something...